# How to compile laravel and vuejs app on live server or run 'npm run watch' command?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-vue

I have a laravel and vuejs application on a live server. I have changed some text and add some features to my vuejs component but It can not affect my frontend. I think I should run 'npm run watch' or 'npm run dev' command but where is cmd? where I can run this command? Help Please

Comment: How did you set it up on your server in the first place?

Comment: Check your hosting provider for instructions on how to SSH into your account.  Also, on a live server, you should be running `npm run production`.  Using `watch` or `dev` are meant for development servers and may expose details of your Vue application through Vue Devtools.

Comment: You should be running those commands locally and only pushing the compiled version to production. Therefore, you just need npm installed locally to be able execute npm commands. In your case you will also need laravel-mix installed to be able to run webpack, which compiles your assest.